# How can I combining the following RegExs into one expression?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm using the following RegEx to strip HTML tags from a string

```
<[^>]*>
```

This does not get rid of blank lines, however. I found this other RegEx that successfully removes any blank lines:

```
[#Chr(13)##Chr(10)#]+
```

I tried to combine both as such:

```
ReReplaceNoCase(arguments.string, "(<[^>]*>)([#Chr(13)##Chr(10)#]+)", "", "ALL")
```

But this does not work. I'm using ColdFusion to do this, which should explain the `#` signs.

I thought the `()` were used to group operators in RegEx, but it does not seem to work in my attempt to combine the two expressions.

Comment: Why do you need to combine them into a single regular expressions? Can't you do it in two steps?

Comment: mandatory read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Mark, I can, but isn't it more efficient to run the string through one function rather than two? If not, why?

Comment: Have you measured the performance of the two-step solution and found it to be the bottleneck in your application? If not, you might be prematurely optimizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the two regular expressions you have work as you want then you can combine them using an alternation:

```
<[^>]*>|[#Chr(13)##Chr(10)#]+
```

I strongly suspect though that the regular expressions you have posted *don't* in fact work correctly. I'd advise you *not* to use regular expressions to parse HTML as HTML is not a regular language. Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Mark, all I want to do is get rid of HTML in a string in order to use it in the "title" attribute of a span or an anchor; I should not use regular expressions for this?

Comment: @Mel:  Your question is like saying "All I want to do is *remove* some screws - not screw them in. And they're only *small* screws so I don't think I need a screwdriver. Won't a hammer work in this case?" - Well, it *might* work *some* of the time, but it's still not the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I got it. I'll try and find a function in ColdFusion that does this. I'm just so used to seeing people use RegEx for this purpose I thought it was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
stripcr(ReReplaceNoCase(arguments.string, "(<[^>]*>)", "", "ALL"))
```