# What's the best way to remove HTML from a string?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I recently started using the following RegEx in a ReReplace() function to strip HTML tags from a string using ColdFusion. **Please note: I am not using this as protection from XSS or SQL injection;** this is only to remove existing and safe HTML from a string before it's displayed in an HTML title attribute.

```
REReplaceNoCase(str,"<[^>]*>","","ALL")
```

In a semi-related question [I asked how to modify my RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540036/how-can-i-combining-the-following-regexs-into-one-expression) to include spaces and line breaks. I was told that using RegEx for this purpose is not appropriate and [this post was referenced as an explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

> I strongly suspect though that the regular expressions you have posted don't in fact work correctly. I'd advise you not to use regular expressions to parse HTML as HTML is not a regular language. Use an HTML parser instead. ([Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540036/how-can-i-combining-the-following-regexs-into-one-expression/4540050#4540050))

If this is true, what is the appropriate tool for removing HTML from a string before it's displayed? (Baring in mind the HTML is already safe; it's sanitized before entry to the DB).

I am aware of [HTMLEditFormat()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7847.html) and [HTMLCodeFormat()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7848.html), but those two functions do not provide what I need; the earlier replaces special characters with their HTML-escaped equivalents, while the latter does exactly the same but also wraps the string a `<pre>` tag.

What I would like to do is clean a string from HTML and line breaks before I display in an HTML title attribute `<a title="My string without HTML goes here">...</a>`

There are times when the HTML is not necessary. Say you wanted to display an excerpt from a post without the HTML stored along with it, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree with the reasoning you quote.  While HTML should not be *parsed* with regexen, stripping tags is perfect for them.

But you will want to be more careful than just `<[^>]*>`, since that would turn

```
<span title=">">...</span>
```

into the ill-formed

```
">...</span>
```

So you need something like `<([^">]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>` instead.  You can strip out line breaks with character replacement instead of a regex, but if you prefer a regex you can use something like `\n` (or even combine it with the above using alternation, but that's even less efficient).

Comment: Charles, many thanks for the explanation. I will leave this open for a little longer to see if I can encourage any further input. Can you clarify what you meant by using "character replacement"? Is there a particular function that does this? Any further elaboration on the concept would be appreciated.

Comment: I was thinking of `Replace(str, '\n', '', 'all')`.

Comment: Charles, the problem with the string you made is that I can't use it. The double quotes are messing up the function and causing an error, since the whole regEx string has to sit between double quotes... any idea how I can get around this?

Comment: Back-quote: type `"<([^\">]|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*>"`.

Comment: Save the regular expression with into variable with cfsavecontent. For example

Comment: Save the regular expression to a variable using cfsavecontent

Answer (score 1):

Use chilkat html parser [chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/htmltoxmldotnet.asp). We used this in my academic project to fetch all the content and hyperlinks from html pages to build a basic search engine.

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML snippet is to be included in a title, you can probably cover all bases with regexes and enough testing.

Still, as a general hint, if you have to handle a larger snippet, I'd go the XML/DOM way with Java, either by parsing with dom4j and grabbing the text or more likely by Stringbuilding the result with a SAX parser.

[EDIT]When I first answered, I was about to write that the HTML must be reasonably well-formed, but assumed you at least a bit of control on the source. If you don't have it, though, I'll just link quickly to [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) and [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) without, of course, having tested either, but they are definitely the first thing I would test to consume real-world HTML with CF.