# XSS remediation - Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags

Tags: coldfusion, xss, veracode

I'm trying to fix some XSS errors with my code. #getEmailRecord is the line that contains the problem. How do I fix a piece of code like this? The error:  Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS). Veracode cleansing solution: coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.HTMLEditFormat

```
tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="left"><b>To: </b></td>
    <td class="left">#getEmailRecord.EMAIL_TO#</td></tr>    
<tr><td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

Thanks! This is my first time doing something like this so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have sanitize the #getEmailRecord.EMAIL_TO#

I believe this was talked about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651110/cleansing-string-input-in-coldfusion-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Veracode cleansing solution: coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.HTMLEditFormat*  The recommended solution tells you what to do. Wrap any variables which contain user supplied data that you utilize in your code in `#HTMLEditFormat()#`.

```
<td class="left">#HTMLEditFormat(getEmailRecord.EMAIL_TO)#</td></tr>
```

[HTMLEditFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7847.html)

> Description
>   Replaces special characters in a string with their HTML-escaped equivalents.

Add if you are on ColdFusion 10 or newer you have even more options - [EncodeFor Functions](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Functions+e-g)